# python iterating two lists in a tuple and comparing a integer between tem

Tags: python, list, zip, compare, tuples

I have a certain number here...

```
x = 6
```

and Two lists here...

```
list1 = [1, 5, 10]
list2 = [3, 7, 20]
```

I would like to find the position of the certain number, 6, which is in between 5 and 7 from list1 and list2, respectively.

Like 6 is in between the "1st index" of both list1 and list2 (0 based),
which means both lists have to be iterate and compare the numbers

```
for a,b in zip(list1,list2): 
    if a <= x <=b:
```

The details of above for loop is like this

```
[(1,3),(5,7),(10,20)]
```

and the `x` belongs to the 1st index of the tuple [(0),(1),(2)]

How can I get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `next` and `enumerate`:

```
>>> x = 6
>>> next((i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)) if a<=x<=b), None)
1
```

`enumerate` returns both index and item from the the iterable/iterator passed to it, and `next` will return the first item from the iterator otherwise `None`.

```
>>> list(enumerate(zip(list1, list2)))
[(0, (1, 3)), (1, (5, 7)), (2, (10, 20))]
```

Comment: @Karyo `i` is used to store the index returned from `enumerate`: `i, (a,b) = (0, (1,3))` , Assignments like this are called [sequence unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Comment: is there any method to enumerate the tuple in backwards?
like [(2, (1, 3)), (1, (5, 7)), (0, (10, 20))]

Comment: @Karyo You can do that using : `zip(xrange(len(list1)-1, -1, -1), zip(list1, list2))`

Comment: Shell returns NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined.
I'm using ver3.3.2 
and range dose not work either.
TypeError: unorderable types: int() <= tuple()

Comment: @Karyo You must be using Python3, use `range`. Yes, the whole thing goes into `zip`, to see its content pass it to `list()`.

Comment: list(zip(range(len(list1)-1, -1, -1), zip(list1, list2))) works absolutely fine but...

If i do this
    "next((i for i, (a, b) in (zip(range(len(list1)-1, -1, -1)), zip(list1, list2)) if a<=x<=b), None)"
Shell returns the value error
"ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"
cant next work backwards?

Comment: @Karyo There's nothing wrong with `next`, you've placed parenthesis at wrong places: `next((i for i, (a, b) in zip(range(len(list1)-1, -1, -1), zip(list1, list2)) if a<=x<=b), None)`

Comment: You are right! finally I got it. Thank you so much appreciate this.